# Fetch only one column from @ManyToOne relation

Tags: java, jpa

I'm trying to shrink one of my entities, as it does not need to load whole related object. What I would like to achieve, is not load whole entity mapped as @ManyToOne relation, but only one of its field. Lets assume, that we have following two entities (those from sample are made up):

```
@Entity
public class Session {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String someField;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "sessionId", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private User user;
}

@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String username;
    private String address;
    private LocalDateTime lastLogin;
}
```

I would like to end up with smaller Session entity, that would look like:

```
@Entity
public class Session {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String someField;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "sessionId", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private LocalDateTime lastLogin; // lastLogin value from User Entity
}
```

I was trying to achieve that by mixing in @Column annotation, but forgot that its not allowed on @ManyToOne. I was thinking about something like can be done with @ElementCollection:

```
    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(name = "OTHER_TABLE")
    @Column(name = "someFieldFromOtherTable")
    private Set<String> someFieldFromOtherTableValues;
```

Is there possibility, to fetch only one column from reflected entity?

Answer (score 1):

This is what I have in my code. Try it:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_address")
@SecondaryTables({
    @SecondaryTable(name="t_city"),
    @SecondaryTable(name="t_country")
})
public class FirstTable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String street1;
    private String street2;

    @Column(table="t_city")
    private String city;
    @Column(table="t_city")
    private String state;
    @Column(table="t_city")
    private String zipcode;

    @Column(table="t_country")
    private String country;
}
```

Comment: Nice idea, but I got an error during save of entity that is mapped to secondary table. Apparently secondary table cannot be mapped as entity.